# Newtonsoft Json Serialize/Deserialize nested property

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization, json-serialization

I have the following class structure

```
public class MainClass
{
   public string MyStringValue {get;set;}
   public SecondClass MyClassValue {get;set;}
}

public class SecondClass
{
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

I set the following values:

```
SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass
{
   Value = "Test"
}

MainClass mainClass = new MainClass
{
   MyStringValue = "String Value",
   MyClassValue = secondClass
}
```

When I serialize the class "mainClass" I get the following Json (which is absolutely clear for me):

```
{
  "MyStringValue":"String Value",
  "MyClassValue":
  {
     "Value":"Test"
  }
}
```

There are cases where I want to have to serialized to the following instead:

```
{
  "MyStringValue":"String Value",
  "MyClassValue": "Test"
}
```

The field name of the sub-class is always "Value", how can this be done?
(And I also need to have a deserializen for the same structure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using a [Custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) with the [JsonConverterAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeProperty.htm). For example, you could create a custom converter for your class:

```
public class SecondClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SecondClass);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            {
                return new SecondClass
                {
                    Value = reader.Value.ToString()
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException($"Error converting value {reader.Value} to type '{objectType}'.", ex);
        }

        throw new JsonSerializationException($"Unexpected token {reader.TokenType} when parsing {nameof(SecondClass)}.");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        var secondClass = (SecondClass)value;
        writer.WriteValue(secondClass.Value);
    }
}
```

And then you would use the `JsonConverterAttribute` with that converter:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SecondClassConverter))]
    public SecondClass MyClassValue { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This would then allow all serializations of `MainClass` to use the `WriteJson` method of `SecondClassConverter`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass
    {
        Value = "Test"
    };

    MainClass mainClass = new MainClass
    {
        MyStringValue = "String Value",
        MyClassValue = secondClass
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainClass);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Providing your desired JSON result:

[image]

---

And deserialization would also work, utilizing the `ReadJson` method of `SecondClassConverter`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = "{ \"MyStringValue\":\"String Value\", \"MyClassValue\": \"Test\" }";

    var decodedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(json);

    Console.WriteLine($"decodedJson.MyStringValue: {decodedJson.MyStringValue}");
    Console.WriteLine($"decodedJson.MyClassValue.Value: {decodedJson.MyClassValue.Value}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Providing output as:

[image]

Comment: thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I added it in my global configuration: settings.Converters.Add(new CustomEnumJsonConverter());

Answer (score 0):

the upper json is not same with latter.  Main class cannot be serialized as `{"MyStringValue":"String Value","MyClassValue": "Test"}` without conversion.

```
var resultObjet = new { 
     MyStringValue = mainClass.MyStringValue,
     MyClassValue = mainClass.SecondClass.MyClassValue
}
```

then you can serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to so this you need a new class for deserialization. However for serialization you can just create an anonymous type on the fly, like so:

```
void Main()
{
    // import Newtonsoft.JsonConvert

    SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass
    {
        Value = "Test"
    };

    MainClass mainClass = new MainClass
    {
        MyStringValue = "String Value",
        MyClassValue = secondClass
    };

    // The JSON as you expect
    var origJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mainClass);
    Console.WriteLine(origJson);
    // The JSON Deserialized and the second class value outputted
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainClass>(origJson).MyClassValue.Value);

    // The modified JSON as you wanted it
    var modJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { mainClass.MyStringValue, MyClassValue = mainClass.MyClassValue.Value });
    Console.WriteLine(modJson);

    // The modified JSON deserialized
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModMainClass>(modJson);
    Console.WriteLine(deserialized.MyStringValue);
}

public class ModMainClass
{
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    public string MyClassValue { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
   public string MyStringValue {get;set;}
   public SecondClass MyClassValue {get;set;}
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices one is what @Simonare mentioned

or change the structor of your class `MainClass` to

```
public class MainClass<T>
{
    public string MyStringValue { get; set; }
    public T MyClassValue { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and now you can simply choose what to use as `MyClassValue`

```
var c = new MainClass<string>();
```

Or

```
 var c = new MainClass<SecondClass>();
```